# how to clear cookie contents with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How do I clear cookie contents with Javascript?  I have the following code:

```
//set cookie for page
document.cookie="username=John Doe";

//alert the cookie
alert('mycookie=' + document.cookie);

//expire the cookie - set expires to yesterday
var yesterdayTicks = new Date().getTime() + (-1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //- 1 day
var yesterday = new Date(yesterdayTicks);
document.cookie = "=;expires=" + yesterday + ";";

//validate cookie update
alert('mycookie=' + document.cookie);
```

I thought expiring the cookie was essentially used as a way to delete the cookie?  Will the page skip loading the cookie if the expires date is set to yesterday?  I'm guessing that in the example above the cookie is still readable after expiring it because it was expired in script within the same request.  Please confirm.

Also, do you ever find it helpful to clear the cookie contents as opposed to just setting an expire date on the cookie?  How would you clear the cookie contents in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an expire date should be enough

```
function clearCookie (name) {
   document.cookie = name +'=;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'
}
```

Comment: The name is the name of the cookie you wish to remove.

Comment: what if I want to remove all cookies that may be associated with the page?

Comment: but how would I identify all cookies to be cleared?  I want to clear all cookies without caring about the names of the cookies

Comment: To get all the cookies you need to parse the *cookie* variable, this how you can get "all" the cookies: *document.cookie.split(";");*, just try it. But Some cookies (especially authentication cookies) are not visible to javascript, but you can see them in firebug for instance, they have set httpOnly flag to true. To get all cookies call this *document.cookie.split(";").map(function(c) { return c.split("=")[0]; })*

Comment: Based on the code you provided it looks like the document.cookie browser property has some underlying logic. For example, when an attempt is made to set the property, the property does a lookup of the requested cookie by name.  Then it sets the additional information provided. So the underlying implementation seems to be more complex than a standard setter property.  Is this correct?

Comment: I have a business requirement that is asking to clear all cookies and I think they are especially interested in clearing any type of authentication cookies.  Sounds like you're saying that documentation.cookie would most likely not include these types of cookies?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Cookies marked with flag httpOnly are protected from reading by javascript, you can not remove this cookies by javascript, you can do it only on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I always make a function like this:

```
export const eraseCookie = (name) => {
    document.cookie = `${name}=; Max-Age=-99999999;`;
};
```

And then use it like:

```
eraseCookie('sessionid');
```

P.S. This is from the production app :)